# why can't you make encrypted values searchable, and still conceal matching values, by storing encrypted "match lists" in a separate table?

Tags: encryption

I was searching for information about whether you could encrypt a column in a table in such a way that it's still possible to build an index that lets you search efficiently (log n time) for a matching value.

Most of the pages that talk about this either say to use a "blind index" hmac(hmac_key, value) which you can index on, or to use homomorphic encryption.  But if you store the hmac alongside the ciphertext, that means an attacker can see when two rows are storing the same value, and if you use homomorphic encryption, that limits your choice of algorithms.

I don't understand why the following isn't a valid simple solution, which does operations in efficient time, hides duplicate from an attacker, and lets you use any algorithm you want:

- In one column of your main table, store values encrypted using non-deterministic encryption (so the same plaintext won't have matching ciphertexts in different rows).
- Create another table with two columns:

  - hmac(value, hmac_key)
  - encrypted_list_of_matching_rows_in_main_table

Then when you add a new value to the table, you first encrypt it and store the encrypted value in the first table.  Then you compute the hmac of the value and look up an entry in the second table.  If there is a matching row, decrypt the list, add your new entry to the list of matching rows, and then re-encrypt the list.  (If there is no matching entry in the second table, create a new entry.)

You do have to consider the worst case where many or all of the values you're storing are the same value, then in the second table, one of your entries contains a long list-of-matching-rows.  For this reason, the "list of matching rows" that you're storing could be in the form of a binary tree, where each node value is encrypted.  It seems you could perform all the usual binary tree operations by traversing it normally -- to store a value, you reach a node, you decrypt the node value, you compare it to the value you're storing, and then you go either left or right -- so adding and deleting should still be log(n).

Then:
- adding a new value is log(n) (you encrypt it and add a new row in your first table, and then you look up the hash of the value in your second table -- which is log(n) since you have an index on the hash -- and then you add a new value to the list for that hash, which is log(n) if it's stored as a binary tree)
- deleting a value is similarly log(n)
- an attacker cannot tell if two rows in the main table are storing the same cleartext value

In this naïve implementation, the second table would still reveal information about values stored in the first table -- for example, the number of rows reveals the number of distinct values.  But you could pad the second table with dummy rows (so the attacker can't tell how many values are stored in the first table) and dummy long lists (so the attacker can't tell if there are any values that legitimately have a large number of matching rows).

Am I missing something?  Or is this valid, but homomorphic encryption or some other technique lets you do the same thing even faster?

Comment: Isn't this identical to the blind index you describe? It shows precisely which rows have equal values, in the same way (using the encrypted_list_of_matching_rows_in_main_table column). I would think a single JOIN could make the two solutions completely identical.

Comment: But what I mean is that if the list of matching rows is encrypted, only a person who has the key would be able to decrypt that list and see that two rows in the first table are storing the same value.  Whereas if the row just contains hmac(key, value), even an attacker who doesn't have the key would be able to tell that two rows are storing the same value.